# How do I create a derived http(s) server in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, inheritance, webserver

I want to derive the Node.js http(s) server, as I need to add some behavior.

E.g., I want to have an http server that also has a `foobar` function. So I want to be able to do something like this:

```
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) { ... }).listen(3000);
server.foobar();
```

Of course I *somehow* need to derive from the `http` module, but how could I do this? Apparently there is no `Http` constructor I could override ...

Any ideas or hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way is to create a subclass of the server.

```
var http = require('http')

class MyServer extends http.Server {
  foobar () {
    // any code
  }
}

var server = new MyServer(function (req, res) {
  // any code
})
```

If you are running a version of Node.js that is <1.0 you need to use the old class syntax:

```
var http = require('http')

function MyServer (handler) {
  http.Server.call(this, handler)
}

MyServer.prototype = Object.create(http.Server.prototype)

MyServer.prototype.foobar = function () {
  // any code
}

var server = new MyServer(function (req, res) {
  // any code
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested, but giving in it a though I would say you would only have to:

```
var http = require('http');
http.Server.prototype.foobar = function () {};
```

As you can see [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/http.js#L84) the createServer function is nothing but a factory instantiating a new Server object that was exposed two lines before.

Comment: This is modifying every instance of `Server` which could potentially mess up any other code. Please don't do this.

Comment: @LinusUnnebäck you're absolutely right! This was answered two years ago. We both advise against this.